# Can I retry for failed tests in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Can I ask for failed tests in pytest
Some number of restarts (retries).
For example: if 2 attempts fail and the third succeeds, then the total result succeeds

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK, this is implemented in [pytest-rerunfailures](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-rerunfailures) plugin. Take a look into.

e.g.

```
$ pip install pytest-rerunfailures
$ pytest --reruns 5
```

---

2023 update: later versions of pytest bundle [relevant functionality](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/cache.html)

Comment: Working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **pytest-rerunfailures** package is a good approach, but sometimes it may not be strong enough. If you need custom options, this implementation can be useful.

```
from pytest import fixture
from functools import wraps
import time


def retry_test(stop_max_attempt_number=5, wait_fixed=5):
    def decorator(test_func_ref):
        @wraps(test_func_ref)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            retry_count = 1

            while retry_count < stop_max_attempt_number:
                try:
                    return test_func_ref(*args, **kwargs)

                except AssertionError as assert_error:
                    assert_message, _ = assert_error.__str__().split("\n")
                    print(f"Retry error: \"{test_func_ref.__name__}\" --> {assert_message}. "
                          f"[{retry_count}/{stop_max_attempt_number - 1}] Retrying new execution in {wait_fixed} second(s)")
                    time.sleep(wait_fixed)
                    retry_count += 1

            # Preserve original traceback in case assertion Failed        
            return test_func_ref(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator


class Test:
    @fixture(scope="class")
    def env(self):
        return {
            "retry": 10,
            "sleep": 5,
            "data": iter([{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 10}])

        }

    @retry_test(stop_max_attempt_number=5, wait_fixed=2)
    def test_product(self, env):
        message_product = next(env["data"], None)
        print(f"Reading message. {message_product}")

        if message_product["id"] == 10:
            assert True, "Message was intercepted"

        else:
            assert False, f"No message arrived"
```

Output

```
Reading message. {'id': 1}
Retry error: "test_product" --> No message arrived. [1/4] Retrying new execution in 2 second(s)
Reading message. {'id': 2}
Retry error: "test_product" --> No message arrived. [2/4] Retrying new execution in 2 second(s)
Reading message. {'id': 3}
Retry error: "test_product" --> No message arrived. [3/4] Retrying new execution in 2 second(s)
Reading message. {'id': 4}
Retry error: "test_product" --> No message arrived. [4/4] Retrying new execution in 2 second(s)
Reading message. {'id': 5}
FAILED
retry_helper.py:40 (Test.test_product)
self = <helpers.retry_helper.Test object at 0x0000021F2793EF28>
env = {'data': <list_iterator object at 0x0000021F2793EF60>, 'retry': 10, 'sleep': 5}

    @retry_test(stop_max_attempt_number=5, wait_fixed=2)
    def test_product(self, env):
        message_product = next(env["data"], None)
        print(f"Reading message. {message_product}")
    
        if message_product["id"] == 10:
            assert True, "Message was intercepted"
    
        else:
>           assert False, f"No message arrived"
E           AssertionError: No message arrived
E           assert False

retry_helper.py:50: AssertionError
```