# Is it possible to implement a hook in pytest to re-run failed tests and change the outcome to 'passed' if the second attempt passes?

Tags: python, pytest, hook

Below is the current state of my pytest hook. Ive gotten this working relatively well, but I need some help seeing if my goal is actually possible.

Right now, I can use this hook to re-run a test upon first failure, and attempt that test one more time in order to assume the test really did fail or not. I am in UI testing and I know that this is a horrible practice, but this is for a proof of concept. UI testing in my area generally leads to flaky results.

This code works, but my setup and teardown functions are not being accessed during the re-run. Is it possible to call the setup and teardown here?

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    report = yield
    result = report.get_result()
    if result.outcome == 'failed':
        try:
            # Run the original tests teardown
            # Run the tests setup
            attempt = item.runtest()
            # Run the tests teardown
        except:
            attempt = 'failed'
        if not attempt:
            result.outcome = 'passed'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I retry for failed tests in Pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967150/can-i-retry-for-failed-tests-in-pytest)

Comment: Also have a look at https://pypi.org/project/pytest-retry/

Comment: Not quite, that wrapper only uses the item.runtest() as well, it doesn't touch theteardown function

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? I recommend using something like `rerun failures` (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-rerunfailures) which is actively maintained and does what you want.